# JUnit/Mockito: ArgumentCaptor running before the JUnit test executes?

Tags: spring, junit, mocking, mockito

I have JUnit test such as follows:

```
@Autowired
MyService myservice;

@Before
public void init() {
   myservice.doStuff(new MyObj());
}

@Test
public void test() {
   ArgumentCaptor<MyObj> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyObj.class);
   myservice.doStuff(new MyObj());
   verify(myservice, atLeastOnce()).doStuff(captor.capture());
   captor.getAllValues(); //this returns 2 - one for the @Before and one for right above
}
```

As mentioned in the commented code, the captor captures both invocation even though the captor is created after the @Before. Why is this and how can I capture only invocation within the test ?

Answer (score 1):

Something looks wrong in this flow, I'll explain and hopefully this will lead you to the solution:

First of all, `ArgumentCaptor` is used only with mocks. So `myservice` has to be a mock, 
I was expecting to see something like `@MockBean` on it or maybe `@Mock` if you're running a plain mockito test without spring.

Now assuming it is a mock, why would you call a method `doStuff` on the mock in `@Before` phase. I can understand if you want to setup some global expectations applicable to all the tests in the class in case you have many, but this seems suspicious to me.

Now, when you use the `verify` what you actually say is:

Mockito, make sure that my mock `myservice` called method `doStuff` (at least once) and for futher verification I would like to "capture" the arguments that were passed to the mock while the method invocation (s).

With this approach its understandable that argument capture gets all the information about all the invocations, and I believe its by design.

To make a point clear, `@Before` method has nothing to do with mockito, its a purely JUnit hook, so by the time it is called by JUnit framework, all mocks are already inialized and are ready to "record" all the relevant information about everything that the code will do to them (method invocations I mean).

Comment: So this was just an example to illustrate the problem....in the real code, the test setup code in `@Before` internally ends up invoking the service(which is actually a `@SpyBean` in real code)...so we always end up getting one or two extra invocations from the setup code...I was wondering if there was a way to exclude those(other than manually filtering out before verification)